# How To display user Friendly name from Enum in DropDownList in MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, enums

Currently in my mvc View Displaying Enum value in DropDownList,But  name " Brittish_Airways" not look user friendly ,trying to replace  "Brittish Airways" insted of " Brittish_Airways" in my view ,How To do it?

show special character/symbol spaces in the enumdropdowlist

My Enum:-

```
 public enum EventType
 {
        Other = 0,
        Birth = 1,
        Marriage = 2,
        Death = 3,
       Brittish_Airways=4
}
```

My reference Code:->

```
  <li>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EventTypeText,
                                   Enum.GetNames(typeof(ABC.Web.EventType))
                                  .Select(e => 
                                           new SelectListItem { Text = e 
                                         }),
                                   new { @class = "ddlEventType ddl" })
 </li>
```

Comment: check my article, as i did in my case:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2015/03/binding-enum-with-dropdownlist-in.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to first create attribute for Enum which will be used on Enum fields for setting Display Name which will be user friendly :

```
public class EnumDisplayNameAttribute : Attribute
{
  private string _displayName;
  public string DisplayName
  {
      get { return _displayName; }
      set { _displayName = value; }
  }
}
```

and then you have to decorate attribute on your enum fields like this:

```
public enum EventType
{
        [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName="Some User Friendly Name")]
        Other = 0,
        [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName="Some User Friendly Name")]
        Birth = 1,
        [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName="Some User Friendly Name")]
        Marriage = 2,
        [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName="Some User Friendly Name")]
        Death = 3,
        [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName="Some User Friendly Name")]
        Brittish_Airways=4
}
```

and now add following extension method for Enum to your existing Extension Methods class or create a new one named EnumExtensions:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static System.Web.Mvc.SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum obj)
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible // correct one
    {

    return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<Enum>()
        .Select(x =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.DisplayName(),
                Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString()
            }), "Value", "Text");

    }


   public static string DisplayName(this Enum value)
   {
       FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

       EnumDisplayNameAttribute attribute
               = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(EnumDisplayNameAttribute))
                   as EnumDisplayNameAttribute;

       return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.DisplayName;
   }
}
```

Now in your view use the extension method to return Enum fields as SelectList with User Friendly name as Text of options:

```
@using YourNamespace.ExtensionMethods;

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EventTypeText,
                                EventType.Other.ToSelectList()), 
                                new { @class = "ddlEventType ddl" })
```

you can also check [my article (Binding Enum with DropdownList in asp.net mvc )](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2015/03/binding-enum-with-dropdownlist-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

From MVC 5.1 and above version, They have added this new helper. You just need an enum

```
public enum Month
    {
        [Display(Name = "January")]
        jan,
        [Display(Name = "February")]
        feb
    }
```

In the enum  [Description("...") is also available, but do read/research it before you use it with EnumDropDownListFor (I have used Display(Name) only).

Then,

You can create the EnumDropDownlist showing the names by writing:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Month, null, new { @id = "ddlMonth", @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px;" })
shareeditflag
```