# Populating a DropDownListFor with enum using display names

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to populate a drop down list using an enum with MVC4. I have the following enum with a `Display` attribute:

```
public enum PlatformEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "--- Please Select ---")]
    Undefined = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Android")]
    Android = 1,
    [Display(Name = "iOS")]
    iOS = 2
}
```

In my view I have the following drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Platform, Model.DropDownPlatform)
```

However, the display values in the drop down list are:

```
Undefined
Android
iOS
```

I need `Undefined` to display as `--- Please Select ---`. Is this possible using display attributes?

Comment: Refer the second highest voted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: refer this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525359/how-to-display-user-friendly-name-from-enum-in-dropdownlist-in-mvc-view